# font face causes performance issues

Tags: css, font-face

When my site loads there is a freeze of a few seconds before the browser displays text that is rendered with font face (text with arial font gets displayed immediately).

I've been getting complaints from users that experience a freeze of up to 10 seconds.

What can I do about that?

here is how I insert the font face:

```
@font-face{
    font-family:'GillSans';
    src:url('../fonts/GIL_____.eot');
    src:url('../fonts/GIL_____.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('../fonts/GIL_____.woff') format('woff'),
        url('../fonts/GIL_____.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('../fonts/GIL_____.svg#GillSans') format('svg');
}
@font-face{
    font-family:'GillSansB';
    src:url('../fonts/GILB____.eot');
    src:url('../fonts/GILB____.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('../fonts/GILB____.woff') format('woff'),
        url('../fonts/GILB____.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('../fonts/GILB____.svg#GillSansB') format('svg');
}
@font-face{
    font-family:'GillSansBI';
    src:url('../fonts/GILBI___.eot');
    src:url('../fonts/GILBI___.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('../fonts/GILBI___.woff') format('woff'),
        url('../fonts/GILBI___.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('../fonts/GILBI___.svg#GillSansBI') format('svg');
}
@font-face{
    font-family:'GillSansI';
    src:url('../fonts/GILI____.eot');
    src:url('../fonts/GILI____.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('../fonts/GILI____.woff') format('woff'),
        url('../fonts/GILI____.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('../fonts/GILI____.svg#GillSansI') format('svg');
}
```

Comment: What is the size of the font ? What browsers experience issues you describe ?

Comment: actually, it's chrome that experience the most lag

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try compressing and caching your fonts. If you use Apache, you can configure this using .htaccess

Here is a very [helpful overview](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/10/13/font-face-and-performance/) from the performance guru Steve Sounders

**Additional info and resources**

Assuming you use Apache and the modules [mod_expires](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_expires.html) and [mod_deflate](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_deflate.html) are enabled, you can add the following rules to your .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  Header set cache-control: public
  ExpiresActive on

  ExpiresByType font/ttf      "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType font/woff     "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 month"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|svg)$" >
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

After adding the above to .htaccess, observe the relevant header fields to verify.

Should you be interested in learning more, check out speed tips for [cache control](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/apache-speed-cache-control.html), and [compression](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/apache-speed-compression.html).

Comment: "_Typekit is clearly on to something – the use of custom fonts has tripled in one year. **I warn against using @font-face for performance reasons**, but performance isn’t all that matters. (Gasp!) Custom fonts obviously have aesthetic benefits that are attractive to website owners._" [Steve Souders, Nov 2011](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2011/11/17/add-your-site-custom-fonts/)

Comment: very interesting article. the thing i can't understand is how to cache the font files?

Comment: I've added additional info. Good luck!